Formula for calculating a running pace progression
I'd like to calculate my target running pace for each mile/kilometer in a progression run (where each mile/kilometer is faster than the last), given a target finish time, and a target "spread" (how much faster each mile/kilometer should be than the last).
For example, say I'm doing a 5k race, my targets might look like this:

target finish time: 25:15
target spread: 15s

The individual kilometers would look like this:



km
pace
cumulative time




1
5:30
5:30


2
5:15
10:45


3
5:00
15:45


4
4:45
20:30


5
4:30
25:15



Given the inputs of a target finish time, a target spread, and a kilometer number, how can I calculate the target pace of each kilometer?
(I've presented times in MM:SS format here for exposition's sake, but I figure the calculation itself would be done in seconds.)

Let's define some notation:

$n$ is the length of the run (an integer number of miles/kilometers/whatever length unit you're using, which I'll call "laps", although a mile would be a pretty long track!)
$t$ is the finish time (in seconds)
$s$ is the spread (in seconds)

We want to find $f$, the time for the first lap.  The time for the $k$th  witll be $f-(k-1)s$.  We have
$$f + (f-s) + (f-2s) + \cdots + (f-(n-1)s) = t$$
and there are $n$ laps here, so we can write this as
$$nf - (s + 2s + 3s + \cdots + (n-1)s) = t$$
But we have $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + (n-1) = n(n-1)/2$.  So this becomes
$$nf - {n(n-1) \over 2} s = t$$
and so you can solve for $f$ to get
$$f = {t \over n} + {n-1 \over 2} s.$$
In your example you have $t = 1515, s = 15, n = 5$ so this gives $f = (1515/5) + 2 \times 15 = 303 + 30 = 333$, or 5 minutes, 33 seconds. The remaining lap times would be 5:18, 5:03, 4:48, 4:33.  (These don't agree with what you gave in your example since you  made an arithmetic mistake in going from lap 4 to lap 5.)
There's a nice explanation for this - the "middle" lap should take time $t/n$, which is the average lap time you need.  The first lap is $(n-1)/2$ laps before that, so you can add $(n-1)/2$ times the spread to get the time for the first lap.  (This works intuitively if $n$ is odd, not so much if $n$ is even.)  The formula will also work if $s$ is negative, which would correspond to slowing down, instead of speeding up, over the course of the run.

Beautiful! I couldn't quite formalize the sequence. This is just what I was looking for. Thank you!

It's easier to "work backwards" in some sense --- You want your cumulative time to be 25:15 (i.e. $1515$ seconds).  If you had run at your maximum pace for every kilometer, you would have
$$\underbrace{0\cdot 15}_{\textrm{first lap}} + \underbrace{1\cdot15}_{\textrm{sec. lap}}+\underbrace{2\cdot15}_{\textrm{third lap}}+\underbrace{3\cdot15}_\textrm{fourth lap}+\underbrace{4\cdot15}_\textrm{fifth lap} = 15\cdot\frac{5\cdot(5-1)}{2} = 150$$
more seconds in your total time.  (Note that I'm simplifying the sum using the triangle number formula $1+2+\cdots+n-1 = \frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}$.)
So, your cumulative time if you ran at the slowest pace for every lap would be $1515+150=1665$ seconds.  Divide this evenly across the $5$ laps, and you will need your slowest lap to be $\frac 1665 5 = 333$ seconds, or 5:33.
(Note: this doesn't match your example because the lap times you've listed do not sum to the cumulative time you've listed.)
